# PL/SQL runtime error when an exception is raised

Tags: plsql

I've written a couple of PL/SQL procedures and they run fine except when I try to test them to get an exception raised on purpose. Probably something with the syntax of declaring or raising the exception? I can't find my error with my exception syntax though

I have no issue when it runs through without triggering the exceptions, but when it hits my exceptions, instead of outputting what I want it to, it says "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: etc..."

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SPLIT_STOCK (p_stock_id IN NUMBER,p_split_factor IN NUMBER)
AS
l_multiplied_shares  NUMBER;
l_new_shares NUMBER;
l_current_shares NUMBER;
l_number_of_shareholders NUMBER;
l_company_id NUMBER;
l_shares_authorized NUMBER;
SPLIT_FACTOR_LESS_THAN_1_EXC EXCEPTION;
SHARES_EXCEEDED_EXC EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
IF p_split_factor <=1 THEN  RAISE SPLIT_FACTOR_LESS_THAN_1_EXC ;  END IF; --Share split factor has to be > 1.

SELECT sum(CShSh.shares) * p_split_factor into l_multiplied_shares from Current_Shareholder_Shares CShSh where CShSh.stock_id = p_stock_id;  --Getting the new total shares after the split
select authorized into l_shares_authorized from shares_authorized sa where sa.stock_id = p_stock_id; --getting number of authorized shares into local variable
select sum(shares) INTO l_current_shares from Current_Shareholder_Shares CShSh where CShSh.stock_id = p_stock_id; --getting the current total shares for this stock
if l_multiplied_shares > l_current_shares THEN RAISE SHARES_EXCEEDED_EXC; END IF; --Did we exceed allowed shares? Raise exception if so.
l_new_shares := l_multiplied_shares - l_current_shares; --This is the new amount of shares to be split evenly among current Shareholders.
Select count(shareholder_id) into l_number_of_shareholders from Current_Shareholder_Shares CShSh where CShSh.stock_id = p_stock_id; --This is the number of shareholders, we need to divide by this number to issue everyone their share of the split shares.
select com.company_id into l_company_id from company com where com.stock_id = p_stock_id; -- getting the company id of the company that is doing the split.

INSERT INTO trade -- (trade_id, stock_id, transaction_time,shares,stock_ex_id,price_total,buyer_id,seller_id,buy_broker_id,sell_broker_id)

               SELECT  trade_id_seq.nextval, p_stock_id, SYSDATE, (l_new_shares/l_number_of_shareholders), NULL, NULL, CShSh.shareholder_id , l_company_id, 
               NULL, NULL
               FROM Current_Shareholder_Shares CShSh;
EXCEPTION
WHEN SPLIT_FACTOR_LESS_THAN_1_EXC THEN dbms_output.put_line ('Please enter a split factor greater than 1. Decimals are also allowed.');
WHEN SHARES_EXCEEDED_EXC THEN dbms_output.put_line ('Number of Authorized shares has been exceeded. split factor needs to be smaller.');
END
;
/



EXEC SPLIT_STOCK(6,100001); -- this should throw my specific defined exception
EXEC SPLIT_STOCK(6,0.5); -- this should throw my specific defined exception
```

Comment: Works for me as written. Maybe a character encoding issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL*Plus will convert the line `EXEC text` into `BEGIN text END;`, adding a semicolon after `text` if `text` does not end with one.

So, in your case, the line

```
EXEC SPLIT_STOCK(6,100001); -- this should throw my specific defined exception
```

becomes

```
BEGIN SPLIT_STOCK(6,100001); -- this should throw my specific defined exception; END;
```

The syntax highlighting in Stack Overflow should give you a hint as to what has happened here: the `END;` has been commented out.  Strange as it may seem, the problem is actually with the comment!

You can see the line SQL*Plus sent to the database in the second line of the error message you get back:

```
SQL> EXEC SPLIT_STOCK(6,100001); -- this should throw my specific defined exception
BEGIN SPLIT_STOCK(6,100001); -- this should throw my specific defined exception; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 0:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the
following:
```

Because you're using `EXEC`, SQL*Plus doesn't wait for a single line `/` to tell it the input has ended. It can send the line to the database straight away, but of course the database will return an error because it can't find the end of the block.

The simplest fix is therefore to delete the comments from your `EXEC` lines.  Alternatively, use a `/* ... */` comment, but take care *not* to use a semicolon before the comment:

```
EXEC SPLIT_STOCK(6,100001) /* this should throw my specific defined exception */
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been stuck on this and pulling my hair out since morning. I must have aged 25 years since then.

I don't think I would ever caught this on my own.